# android capturing composite layout to bitmap

Tags: android, layout, bitmap, capture

I need to capture a multi-scroll( meaning it is not a single screen layout, it needs scrolling to see full content) to a Bitmap. I am successfully using the following code pattern for screen layout capturing up to screen size:

```
renderingView.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bmpForSend = renderingView.getDrawingCache(true).copy(Config.RGB_565, false);
renderingView.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Where renderingView is the top layout composed of many View/Layouts.
I do not want to try to do this the way to capture->scroll->capture...
There has to be another way for doing this.